# service worker cache takes time to respond with latency

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

This is my first interaction for using service workers to cache some stuff. As part of my POC i am trying to cache assets like "js", "css" ,

i am using [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox)

```js
(function (global) {
  'use strict';

  // Ensure that our service worker takes control of the page as soon as possible.

  global.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    return event.waitUntil(global.skipWaiting());
  });
  global.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    return event.waitUntil(global.clients.claim());
  });

  // The route for any requests from the googleapis origin
  toolbox.router.get('/(.*)', global.toolbox.cacheFirst, {
    cache: {
      name: 'modjs',
      maxEntries: 30,
      maxAgeSeconds: 86400
    },
    debug: true,
    origin: /\.abc\.com\:8044$/
  });
})(self);
```

I can see network calls are coming from service workers but they are still showing some latency.[image]

Let me what is wrong ?

Comment: Also, can you try again without the `cache: {}` options, which are used to set up cache expiration? They're supposed to be implement in a way that leaves them outside of the critical path of returning the response to the page, but it's one thing to check.

Answer (score -1):

For better page rendering performance, try to linked the `.css` files after the `.js` files. Check the ordering of the files. Make sure also that the user have access to the script file. The project might had their `web.config` denying access to anonymous users.

`Uncaught ReferenceError` bassically means you are trying to access a variable or function that has not been defined yet.

For more details, kindly check this document: https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2015/service-workers-iowa#top_of_page

Comment: sorry for run snippet  to  be confusing here. I am not getting any error. My query is more related to why network latency is there even i am pulling resources from service worker.